# how to set utf in HTTP GET, using JAVA

Tags: java, json, string, utf-8, json-deserialization

I am receiving special character as "ñ" or "á , é" etc in a response of Get request . The code is the next :

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
BufferedReader b_r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getInputStream())));
String data = b_r.readLine();
```

How can I set utf-8 in order to receive the proper characters?

Comment: The server is using UTF-8 by default, no other intervention is required.

Comment: @nikpon: How do you know that? It *should* be using UTF-8, but it may not be... and the OP's code *doesn't* use UTF-8, unless that's the default encoding on their platform.

Comment: For the OP: it would really help if you'd tell us what you're currently observing, and what diagnostic tests you've performed so far. You don't "set utf in json" - but you *can* specify how you decode binary data back into text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally, don't use this code at all - use a JSON parser which accepts an `InputStream`, instead of reading it line by line.

If you need, specify UTF-8 as the encoding to the `InputStreamReader`, as you're currently just using the platform default encoding:

```
BufferedReader b_r = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader((connection.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
```

This is assuming it really *is* UTF-8 - which it should be, if it's JSON. (If the server *isn't* sending UTF-8, you should try to get that fixed.)